# react native dry conditional statement

Tags: json, firebase, react-native, dry

I have the following piece of code which is all fine and working, but I am looking at how I can better produce this so its DRY, if I can combine all the customisations etc. would be ace

```
render() {
    let sizeHeader,milkHeader = null;
    this.props.data.size ? sizeHeader = <Text style={styles.headerLabel}>Size</Text> : null
    this.props.data.milk ? milkHeader = <Text style={styles.headerLabel}>Milk</Text> : null

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ParallaxScrollView>
          <View>
            {sizeHeader}
            {(this.props.data.size||[]).map((section,i) => (
              <AddToCartRow key={i} data={section} productName={this.props.data.name} value={Config.priceToPriceWithCurrency(section.price)} />
            ))}
            {milkHeader}
            {(this.props.data.milk||[]).map((section,i) => (
              <AddToCartRow key={i} data={section} productName={this.props.data.name} value={Config.priceToPriceWithCurrency(section.price)} />
            ))}
          </View>
      </ParallaxScrollView>
      <RoundedButton onPress={()=>{NavigationActions.CartAndCheckout()}}>
        Go to Cart
      </RoundedButton>
    </View>
  );
}
```

JSON

```
{
  "Merchants" : {
    "items" : [ {
      "address" : "address here",
      "items" : [ {
        "description" : "Silky frothed milk poured over a shot of espresso, topped with a touch of chocolate.",
        "info" : {
          "Calories" : "250 kcal",
          "Glutten Free" : "Yes"
        },
        "milk" : [ {
          "name" : "Full Cream",
          "price" : 0
        }, {
          "name" : "Almond",
          "price" : ".5"
        }, {
          "name" : "Coconut",
          "price" : ".5"
        }, {
          "name" : "Soy",
          "price" : ".5"
        }, {
          "name" : "Cunt",
          "price" : 5
        } ],
        "name" : "Cappuccino",
        "photo" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ed/Wet_Cappuccino_with_heart_latte_art.jpg",
        "price" : 10.0,
        "size" : [ {
          "name" : "Small",
          "price" : 10
        }, {
          "name" : "Medium",
          "price" : 18
        } ]
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_renderContent = (key) => (
  <View>
    {this.props[key] && <Text style={styles.header}>{`${key.charAt(0).toUppercase()}${key.slice(1)}`}</Text>}
    {(this.props[key] || []).map(section, i) => (
      <AddToCartRow
        key={i}
        data={section}
        productName={this.props.data.name}
        value={Config.priceToPriceWithCurrency(section.price)}
      />
    )}
  </View>
);
```

You should pass the key of `props` you want to map.

```
<ParallaxScrollView>
  <View>
    {['milk', 'size'].map(this._renderContent)}
  </View>
</ParallaxScrollView>
```

Comment: do I need to be passing it any arguments?

Comment: Either `milk` or `size`

Comment: so how do I actually pass this arguments to this code?

Comment: still doesn't seem to work and just returns that the argument is undefined when I do a console.log

Comment: @Paul'Whippet'McGuane you mean the `key` is `undefined`?

Comment: Can you share a gist?